# Any solution to convert timestamp to Date and time (with time zone) ? in React.js

Tags: reactjs, date, timestamp, format

I was trying to build a calendar component, but on my backend Jason Api the date is given in timestamp. So how would I going to convert the timestamp to Date and time (with time zone) ?

Consider the code below.

```
const appointments = [
  {
    id: 0,
    title: 'Watercolor Landscape',
    startDate: new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-US').format(1585640511000), // here to convert timestamp 
    endDate: new Date(2018, 6, 23, 11, 30),
    ownerId: 1,
  }
];
```

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      data: appointments,
    };

    this.commitChanges = this.commitChanges.bind(this);
  }

render() {
    const { data } = this.state;
    console.log( data) // I console the data 
    return (
      <Paper>
        <Scheduler
          data={data}
        >
   )
}
```

and here is the result from my console:

[image]

My question is how to convert the type of startDate as same as endDate?

Answer (score 1):

```js
const appointments = [
  {
    id: 0,
    title: 'Watercolor Landscape',
    startDate: new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-US').format(1585640511000), // here to convert timestamp 
    endDate: new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-US').format(new Date(2018, 6, 23, 11, 30).getTime()),
    ownerId: 1,
  }
];
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/docs/). It offers a simple way of parsing a string to a Date object.

```
var date = moment("3/31/2020", "M/DD/YYYY");
```